# how to import .dsc on nmu master branch on git?

Tags: debian, git, packaging

I want to import a package description file (.dsc) on new nmu branch that has master rule.
So, firstly I create new mnu branch: `git branch nmu master`

Then I did `git checkout master`
and

after that I entered `gbp import-dsc -v 2.1 --debian-branch=nmu /home/debianpackaging/package.dsc`.
but it has an error:

```
gbp:error: Need to give exactly one package to import. Try --help.
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in last command, I used "-v" that is incorrect!
The option "-v" is using for "verbos" and because of that, It thinks we have another .dsc file!
by omitting `-v` It will work properly!